# Как определить конструктор, объявленный в классе, вложенном в другой класс (с шаблонами)?

Tags: классы, c++

Надо определить в файле .cpp конструктор класса B.

```
template<typename A_type>
struct A
{
A_type т;

template<typename A_type>
struct B
{
A_type m;
B();
};

};

// cpp файл ошибка
template<typename A_type>
A<A_type>::B<A_type>::B()
{
m;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в B, такой же тип, как и в A, то второе объявление `template<typename A_type>` не нужно. Оно нужно, если в B нужен другой тип.

```
template<typename B_type>
struct B
{
  B_type m;
  B();
};

template<typename A_type>
template<typename B_type>
A<A_type>::B<B_type>::B()
{
}
```